# Given that the graph of $f$ passes through the point $(1, 6)$ and that the slope of its tangent line at $(x, f(x))$ is $2x + 1$, find $f(2)$.

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

As in the title - we assume that the graph of $f$ passes through $(1,6)$ (i.e. $f(1) = 6$) and that the slope of its tangent line at $(x, f(x))$ is $2x + 1$ and we are asked to find $f(2)$.

How does one go about solving for $f(2)$? It would be greatly appreciated if someone could set me off in the right direction :)

Comment: I assume you're familiar with the concept of derivative since you seem to know what integration means (seeing your comment on the answer provided). If so it might be helpful for your understanding if you tried to re-phrase your question (not necessarily here, just for your own profit) in terms of the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find an equation for $f(x)$ by integration
2. Find the value of the constant using $(1,6)$
3. Evaluate $f$ at $x=2$

Comment: So by integrating  the tangents equation, this should give me f's equation i presume?

Comment: Right, and a constant.